# How to make a CASE choose when or else

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a SQL query shown below:

```
SELECT room.roomid,
CASE 
    when state=1 then 'clear'
    when date between start-date and end-date then 'clear'
    else 'unclear'
END as state
FROM room
join clean
on room.roomid=clean.roomid
```

Table **"Room"**:

| RoomId | State | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2012-10-16 |
| 2 | 0 | 2012-10-16 |

Table **"Clean"**:

| CleanId | RoomId | Start-Date | End-Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 232 | 2 | 2012-10-15 | 2012-10-18 |
| 233 | 2 | 2012-08-23 | 2012-08-24 |

**Current Output**:

| Roomid | State |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | clear |
| 2 | clear |
| 2 | unclear |

**Expected Output**:

| Roomid | State |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | clear |
| 2 | clear |

I know that the room is clear at first, because it has been cleared during the 232 clean, but the case is adding another line because the 233 clean is not covering the date of the room state.

How can I say to the CASE that it can only choose when or else and not both please? Or how can I delete the unclear line if I see that the same roomid is clear?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ Where is the task itself?

Comment: seems like the negative case fits better here, something like case when state!= 1 and not date between start-date and end-date then ... else ... end ...Furthermore, the join likely is insufficient. Overall, your query looks very strange.

Comment: Is `join table` supposed to be `join clean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of duplicate rows comes with the `JOIN` operation, as long as the one row "*room.RoomId = 2*" is matched with both two rows of "*Clean.RoomId*".

You can circumvent this problem by forcing the values from the "*Clean*" table to have dates in your required range.

Then you can simplify the check in the `CASE` statement, assigning "*state = clear*" only to those rows with "*room.State = 1*". Any row that is not assigned a "*state*" value to (either "*room.State = 0*" or non satisfying the additional `JOIN` condition on dates) will be assigned "*state = unclear*" by `COALESCE` function.

```
SELECT room.roomid,
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN State = 1 THEN 'clear' END, 'unclear') AS state
FROM      room 
LEFT JOIN clean
       ON room.RoomId = clean.RoomId
      AND room.date_ BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date
ORDER BY RoomId
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i4dCWJ6d6qAUJBRmj7jXB2/0).

Comment: Thank you very much for editing my post to make it clearer as well as giving me a correct answer. My case is way more complicated and uses a lot of tables and I didn't want to include everything. So I tried my best to target and simplify the best I could ! I didn't knew how to use COALESCE function correctly for this situation. Your solution got me the result I want and I understand what I did incorrectly.